# Filtering and ordering

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a news feed app and I need to filter news by category while ordering them by data.

The only way I was able to achieve this was by duplicating the news, one for a category name 'All' and another for the category it belongs.

Is there a way filter by category and order by the timestamp?

Edit:
this is an example of my db structure.

```
news
 -All
    -category: "category1"
    -sortDate: -1477585147
 -Category1
 -Category2
 -Category3
```

Doing this way i am able to filter as i want, but i have to duplicate all the news.

Comment: Which language are you programming in? What is your database JSON structure? What have you tried so far?.. and so on..

Comment: You already seem to know the answer: Firebase Queries can only be order/filtered by a single property. Sometimes it is possible to combine multiple values into a single property. But if it is not possible, you'll have to model your data differently to allow the use-case you want. The structure in your questions seems reasonable for accessing categories by descending data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Duplicating data is quite normal in NoSQL databases (see the [Firebase documentation on modeling scalable data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#fanout) and this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)). Whether there is a better solution is hard to say without seeing a minimal example that of your actual JSON (as text, no screenshot) and the code for yourquery.